# Java thread implementation vs declaration

Tags: java, declaration, runnable, implementation, difference

i'm currently studying Java and i want to know what is the difference between implementing Runnable to a class and declaring a new thread and executing what you need inside.

```
Thread t = new Thread(){

    public void run() {
    //code here
    }
};
t.start();
```

vs

```
Thread t = new Thread(My_class_with_runnable_implementation);
t.start();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["implements Runnable" vs "extends Thread" in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread-in-java)

Comment: I don't want to extends Thread , i would like to call an constructor inside

Comment: Besides those (older) answers, you also want to look at `Callable` which is a new interface like `Runnable` that you should consider using.  Also besides using a `Thread` look at `ExecutorService` and `ThreadPool`.